# Programatically copying files between sites in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, copy-item

What is the guidance for copying files between sites in SharePoint Online? You could do this with the Copy Web service in the past, but I'm not sure how much longer that will be supported.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy(v=office.12).aspx